# Match text between quotes

Tags: ruby, regex

i need to match only text into "".

I tried with this code, but dosen't works :(

```
text = ""This is an example text to be mathed""
text.scan(/^(")$(")/)
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This doesn't make sense. Your sample text doesn't have any double-quotes in it.

Comment: `""This is an example text to be mathed""` is an invalid string definition in Ruby. Perhaps experimenting using IRB on the command line will help you? Try entering `irb` in the console and interactively try your string definition and your scan.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So your example doesn't work because your string is malformed. That is, ""boo"" isn't a Ruby string. You could use single quotes to make a string with double quotes in it and do the match, like so:

```
>> boo = '"Sample text to be matched"'
=> ""Sample text to be matched"\n"
>> boo.scan(/"(.*)"/)
=> [["Sample text to be matched"]]
```

Comment: Using `.*` means `'a "foo bar" and "baz qux"'` will give a match of `'foo bar" and "baz qux'`. Use `/"[^"]*"/`.

Answer (score 0):

A better pattern for matching strings is:

```
/"(\\.|[^"])*"/
```

This will consume backslash escapes, but will stop at the first terminating `"` (unless it is preceded by a backslash).