# Select all text between double quotes (not the quotes themselves) with REGEX

Tags: regex, shell

Using regular expression, I'd like to know how to select all text within double quotes but without also selecting the double quotes.

For example, I want the expression to select "`domain.com`" not `"domain.com"`

Edit: This is to be used in a Shell script but I'm currently testing this out in Notepad++

Comment: possible duplicate of [Match text between quotes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8690449/match-text-between-quotes)

Comment: which language are you using?

Comment: Thanks for spotting that, @MichaelT! The poster of that question was asking within the context of Ruby programming and the answers didn't actually answer the question for me.

Comment: @nu11p01n73R I'm testing it out in Notepad++ at the moment but plan on adding it into a Shell script.

Comment: Note that the search function in Notepad++ is more powerful than the regex in shell (I assume *nix-like shell).

Comment: Are you able to use `grep`?

Comment: `grep -oP '"\K[^"]*' file`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use look arounds

```
(?<=").*?(?=")
```

Example : http://regex101.com/r/oX7xR3/1

- `(?<=")` asserts that `"` is followed. The `"` is not consumed by the engine but checks if it can be matched
- `(?=")` asserts that the string is followed by `"`

Example usage :

```
$ echo \"domain.com\" | grep -oP '(?<=").*?(?=")'
domain.com
```

Comment: I don't think shell supports look-around (assuming a *nix like shell)

Comment: @nhahtdh Op wants to test in notpad++ on which it will work. But for shell, I worry that it may not work

Comment: Thanks for that. The regex worked and that website is a Godsend! I'll test it out - it should be ok.

Comment: @MissM you are welcome. But the lookbehinds maynot work in all shells and platforms. Make sure that that it works for your tool. Or use some  powerfull tools like grep or perl

Comment: I should note that the regex grep uses doesn't allow for lookbehinds but this answer was still very helpful. 
Edit: I just saw your edits and will try them out, @nu11p01n73R. Thanks!

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't work. It still selects the double quotes.

Comment: @MissM it shouldnt. How are you using the command? see the example usage for the `grep`. The `-o` option is required to select the part wich matches the regex

Comment: @nu11p01n73R Actually I tested out your example usage and that worked. Thank you so much for your help. :)

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully I have understood the question. This will capture anything inside double quotes (without the quotes):

```
"(.*)"
```

Comment: Actually, the quotes will be included in the match (so they'll be "selected" too), but the capturing group gives you direct access to the text between them.   Maybe that's sufficient.